# How to allow binary to run with multiple shared library versions

Tags: c++, go, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am trying to compile a binary of a program that has a buildtime + runtime dependency on `libunbound` I compile the binary on a Ubuntu 20.04 Machine (using `go build -tags unbound`) and it works.

When I try to run the same binary on my Arch installation (with `unbound`) installed, I get:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libunbound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

output of `ldd file`:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffffe1b0000)
    libunbound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunbound.so.2 (0x00007fdf775c5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdf773a6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdf76fb5000)
    ...
```

My arch Install does not seem to have `libunbound.so.2`. But it does have `libunbound.so.8`

```
#ldconfig -p | grep unbound                                                                                                            
    libunbound.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libunbound.so.8
    libunbound.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libunbound.so
```

I presume I will have to install whichever package provides me with `libunbound.so.2` (but that looks like a pain to find), is there a way I can bundle `libunbound.so.2` with the binary so it works on all machines/distributions, without the user having to worry about runtime dependencies. I have heard of static linking but I'm unsure if that is what I'm looking for here. My attempts at "static" linking using my limited C/go knowledge got me nowhere.

I am also open to any articles with explanations related to this.

I also tried doing `go build -tags unbound -ldflags="-extldflags=-static"` but got:

```
/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunbound
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-436597878/000004.o: in function `_cgo_26061493d47f_C2func_getaddrinfo':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:58: warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried doing that on the Ubuntu machine (since arch install didn't seem to have a libunbound.a file), I got this instead:

```
/snap/go/7013/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000004.o: In function `_cgo_26061493d47f_C2func_getaddrinfo':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:58: warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_add_ta':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:161: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_add_ta'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_add_ta_file':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:181: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_add_ta_file'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_config':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:201: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_config'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_create':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:218: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_create'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_data_add':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:238: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_data_add'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_data_remove':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:258: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_data_remove'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_debuglevel':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:279: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_debuglevel'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_debugout':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:299: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_debugout'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_get_option':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:332: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_get_option'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_hosts':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:352: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_hosts'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_resolvconf':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:372: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_resolvconf'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_set_fwd':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:392: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_set_fwd'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_set_option':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:413: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_set_option'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_trustedkeys':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:433: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_trustedkeys'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_zone_add':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:454: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_zone_add'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_zone_remove':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:474: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_zone_remove'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_resolve':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:497: undefined reference to `ub_resolve'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_strerror':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:528: undefined reference to `ub_strerror'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_version':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:564: undefined reference to `ub_version'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_ctx_delete':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:314: undefined reference to `ub_ctx_delete'
/tmp/go-link-821192870/000006.o: In function `_cgo_4919ea55c4da_Cfunc_ub_resolve_free':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:512: undefined reference to `ub_resolve_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Yes, if you have a libunbound static library, it's possible to statically link to that. It is going to require some knowledge of how to use the C linker.

Comment: @JimB I tried doing that, but I got a error (edited question with it), Can you point to resources that might help me in doing this?

Comment: `cannot find -lunbound` means you don't have a `libunbound` static library. If you do have that, you will need to specifically link that and whatever else it requires statically. If you want to statically link everything, which is what you tried, you should use a libc that can be statically linked and not glibc (hence the final warning)